# How do I get a subtotals after getting groupby().sum() totals?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas

I hope that subject line makes sense.  I've used the following code to get me the 'Task Minutes' totals and create a new df, which works just fine:

```
>> df1 = df.groupby(['USER','Task'])['Task Minutes'].sum().reset_index(name='Total Task Min')
>> df1

     USER   Task    Total Task Min
0    USER1  TASK1   48.00
1    USER1  TASK2   139.00
2    USER1  TASK3   86.00
```

What I'm trying to do now, is group df1 by 'USER' and 'Task' and sum the minutes, so it looks like this or something similar to get the subtotals of each user:

```
USER   Task    Total Task Min
USER1  TASK1   48.00
       TASK2   139.00
       TASK3   86.00
Total          273.00
```

I can't quite get there.  I'm thinking logically it would be something like:

```
df2 = df1.groupby(['USER'])['Total Task Min'].sum()
```

...but this results in an error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'
```

Comment: What's the output of `df1.groupby(['USER'])['Total Task Min'].sum()` look like?

Comment: Same error:  TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Decimal' and 'float'

Comment: You're on to something though.  I think it has to do to a prior sum() of data.  Do I have to identify the type if I'm using a pre-summed dataframe column?

Comment: I don't think so.  What's your version number?  In the latest version `reset_index()` doesn't have a `name` keyword: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html.

Answer (score 0):

What about this :

```
pd.pivot_table(df1, values=['Total Task Min'], index=['USER'],
               columns=['Task'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True).stack('Task')
Out[75]: 
              Total Task Min
USER   Task                 
 USER1 All               273
       TASK1              48
       TASK2             139
       TASK3              86
All    All               273
       TASK1              48
       TASK2             139
       TASK3              86
```